# gnuplot date in x axis - all points y value undefined

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I am trying plot graph with gnuplot.
I would like to use data and time in x axis but it answers me:
**line 0: all points y value undefined!**

but when I use 1st column (instead of date column it generate graph)

my data file:

```
1 2024-03-09_21-00-01 5.700000
2 2024-03-09_22-00-01 5.700000
3 2024-03-09_23-00-01 5.200000
4 2024-03-10_00-00-03 5.100000
5 2024-03-10_01-00-02 4.900000
6 2024-03-10_02-00-00 4.900000
7 2024-03-10_03-00-02 5.100000
8 2024-03-10_04-00-02 5.500000
9 2024-03-10_05-00-03 5.200000
10 2024-03-10_06-00-03 5.900000
```

my working script (without using date):

```
#!/bin/bash

gnuplot -persist <<-EOFMarker
    set autoscale y 
    set pointsize 0.1
    plot "./hs.txt" using 1:3 with linespoints
EOFMarker
# rest of script, after gnuplot exits
```

my code which uses date at x axis(but answers all points y value undefined!) :

```
#!/bin/bash

gnuplot -persist <<-EOFMarker
    set xdata time
    set timefmt '"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"'
    set xrange ['"2024-03-10_00-00-00"':'"2024-03-10_06-00-00"']
    set format x '"%Y-%m-%d"'
    set autoscale y 
    set pointsize 0.1
    plot "./hs.txt" using 2:3 with linespoints
EOFMarker
# rest of script, after gnuplot exits
```

Please could anybody give me some advice what I am doing wrong?
Thanks all a lot!

Comment: why are you quoting everything twice? eg. `set timefmt '"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"'` says that the format contains literal double-quotes

Comment: Get rid of the single-quotes and just use the double-quotes. Consider creating a plot file (e.g. `yourfile.plt`) that contains your gnuplot commands. Much easier than manipulating a heredoc. Then you can simply `gnuplot -p yourfile.plt`.

Comment: For further info on quoting see the [Gnuplot Manual - Quote Marks](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.4/Gnuplot_5_4.pdf#section*.96)

Answer (score 0):

When I try solve some previous problem, I have found solution with singe and then with double quotes. But it was probably for sam older version of gnuplot. So I have removed single quotes and it is working now. Thanks all for reply.

For sure - workicng code:

```
#!/bin/bash

gnuplot -persist <<-EOFMarker
    set xdata time
    set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"
    set xrange ["2024-03-10_00-00-00":"2024-03-10_06-00-00"]
    set format x "%Y-%m-%d"
    set autoscale y
    set pointsize 0.1
    plot "./hs.txt" using 2:3 with linespoints
EOFMarker
# rest of script, after gnuplot exits
```